# HTC reverse tethering 4.1

Tags: usb-connection-mode, reverse-tether

with Android 4.0 everything was fine, but after upgrading to 4.1 I can no longer activate reverse tethering successfuly.

```
Phone: HTC Desire X with 4.1 upgrade  
Root: no and don't want to  
PC: Windows 7 x64  
AV: ESET Nod32 v4
FW: Comodo v6, currently uninstalled
```

#### Symptom:

changing USB connection mode to "Reverse tethering" makes it attempt to connect and after a minute it displays dialog like (translated) '*Connecting to PC failed: either there is not HTC Sync installed in the newest version* or other device is already using  reverse tethering on your computer***.'
* not true, just installed newest
** no other device is connected

#### Installed - newest versions:

- HTC BMP USB Driver
- HTC Driver Installer
- HTC Sync Manager (recognizes phone, backup works)
- HTC Sync (just in case, HTC SM/drivers should suffice)
- Additionally tried Google USB Driver (via Android SDK)
  (plus ones like RNDIS etc. are as well)

#### Tried & notes:

- with 4.0 everything worked flawlessly, even with these AV&FW active, without installing Sync etc.
- attempts with AV and FW disabled, FW uninstalled at a point
- HTC Sync Manager recognizes phone, backup works
- MTP file transfer works
- HTC Sync does NOT recognize phone (possibly important) (USB Debug has no effect either on/off)
- HTC Sync offers update, after running its install it says there's already a newer one in PC
- Windows driver install dialog after plugging in was all green (one day at least, that is, ofter there are fails: "device disconnected")
- USB debugging either on/off no effect
- Restarting neither phone nor PC has effect
- Completely uninstalled and reinstalled all Android drivers and HTC software
- In Windows Device Manager there are both My HTC and HTC Desire X, both report drivers up to date

Tried googling, two other forums, HTC support is not responding to my question.

What can I do to be able to reverse tether again?
Thank you!

*This is probably a borderline question with superuser (possibly a PC's software issue), not sure which would be better, posted here.*